# Recharging More Than One Battery

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I can't seem to recharge more than one battery. I did a battery upgrade, so I have three available batteries, but the normal recharge only fills up one. I can get another battery to charge up by using an item, but I would think I should be able to recharge them. Am I missing something?

Comment: The system "Recharges any partially charged" bars. if a bar is 100% empty, it will not naturally recharge. This means abilities such as  typhoon, punching through walls or reflex KO/kills will drain a battery completely, no chance or recharge. Invisibility drains batteries partially, so you can use it with 2 bars, get down to 1.1 bars, and recharge the second bar completely.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Technically it's not "the first" battery that recharges, it's just one. If you eat up to your max, the last bar will recharge as long as you don't use any of the second-to-max.

To complicate matters, it seems eating a multiple-battery item (which supposedly restores two energy) will actually only restore your current battery plus one more.  So if you have three batteries, you're halfway through regenerating the first, and you eat a two-battery item, you'll only end up with two batteries (as opposed to the expected two and a half, with the half regenerating).

**TL;DR** - wait for your batteries to recharge before eating anything!

Comment: That's weird since eating an energy bar (restores 1 battery) with only half a battery charged will result in 1.5 batteries.

Comment: Correct - two totally different behaviors, especially considering the two-battery item is supposed to just be a box of the one-battery...